# Java Swing send text from JTextArea to txt file on separate lines

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a `JTextArea`

[image: matrix]

When I write this data to text file, it prints all on the same line:

[image: gribi]

How to make the output of text file to be the same like in text area, on 2 separate lines?

The code of text area, and writing data to text.

```
JTextArea matrixArea = new JTextArea();
matrixArea.setBounds(139, 63, 337, 111);
dataPanel.add(matrixArea);

JButton sendData = new JButton("Send Data");
sendData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String nrPatterns = patternText.getText().toString();
        String inputTex = inputText.getText().toString();
        String otputTex = outputText.getText().toString();
        String matrixW  = matrixArea.getText().toString();

        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.txt", true);
            writer.write(nrPatterns);
            writer.write(" ");
            writer.write(inputTex);
            writer.write(" ");
            writer.write(otputTex);
            writer.write(" ");
            writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            writer.write(matrixW);
            writer.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Success");
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Error", "Error",  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: is split("\n") not working?

Comment: Ah, note pad, you pain in the ... code.  Note pad requires both a `\n` (new line) and `\r` (return) before it will print the lines. You could try loading the file into a different editor or use `System.lineSeparator` and replace all the `\n` characters in the `String`s with it ... as a few ideas of the top the head - [For more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557978/notepad-not-recognizing-new-line-characters-in-java-code-using-printstream-to-ou)

Comment: tried, didn't help :(

Comment: 1) See [`JTextComponent.write(java.io.Writer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write-java.io.Writer-) 2) `matrixArea.setBounds(139, 63, 337, 111);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). ..

Comment: .. Use rows/cols to suggest a size for this text area, and layouts constraints for the positioning. 3) *"tried, didn't help"* Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 4) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this after your last .write:

```
writer.newLine();
```

Comment: You need to use a BufferedWriter to use the newline() method.

Comment: You're right camickr! So change your FileWriter and that's all I hope